# speed up inserting data from Data Set to SQL powershell

Tags: powershell

When I run this script to insert data into table in SQL from DataSet, the process takes a long time to insert it (row by row) .the inserting time depend on the row counts , more rows more time .

is there any way to speed up the process or split the rows to multiple records and insert it parallel on same time .

```
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; $i++) { 
  try { 
    $valuestr = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder 
    for ( $x = 0; $x -lt 11; $x++) { 
      if ($x -lt 10) { 
        [void]$valuestr.Append("'" + $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[$i][$x].ToString().Trim().Replace("'", "/") + "',") 
      } 
      else { 
        [void]$valuestr.Append("'" + $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[$i][$x].ToString().Trim().Replace("'", "/") + "'") 
      } 
    }
    [string]$inputstr = $valuestr.ToString()
    [char[]]$values = $inputstr.ToCharArray()
    [string]$output = ''
    foreach ($letter in $values) {
            
      [int]$value = [Convert]::ToInt32($letter)
      [string]$hexOutput = [String]::Format("{0:X}", $value)
      switch ($hexOutput) {
        "627" { $output += "ا"; Break }
        default { $output += [Convert]::Tostring($letter); break }
      }
    }
    $sqlCmdd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO $sqlTable ([ICN],[ICN_NODE],[PARTITION_ID],[ICN_CREATE_DT] ,[ICN_SEQ_NUM],[ICN_SUBNUM],[ICN_TAG_ID],[ICN_TAG_VER],[BLK_NUM],[BLK_LEN] ,[FREE_FORM_TXT]) Values (" + $output.ToString() + ")" 
    $sqlCmdd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
  }
  catch { $_.Exception.Message | Out-File C:\log\log.txt -Append } 
}
```

Comment: Add a database **transaction** which combines multiple INSERTs.

Comment: You can increase speed by bulking up a some insert statements before sending them off to SQL server. Guessing 100-200 should do it. But your code is very "text based". There are a lot of modules that will simplify the prosess. Look at Out-DataTable and "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy" WriteToServer methods.